# How do I render a single JSON value inside HTML?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

When I return a JSon value, i simply want to put a string inside an existing div

EDIT: Let me Rephrase this: I want my MVC controller to return a JSON object to the UpdateTarget specified in the MVC AJAX call. Instead of returning "content".

Comment: Are you using a particular javascript library to parse this returned JSON data?

Comment: Are you trying to render something extracted from the JSON?  Or are you trying to put a JSON array inside an HTML element, for parsing later somehow?

Comment: trying to extract and display a string

Comment: Post the structure of the JSON String that you have. The code to take a value from a JSON Object is dependent on the structure of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Assume your JSON String looks like this:

```
 var jobj = '{"name":"value"}';
```

and you have a div on the HTML with id mycontentdiv then

```
 document.getElementById("mycontentdiv").innerHTML = jobj.name;
```

will take the "value" and place it in the div.

Without further details it is difficult to be more specific.

Comment: er, lose the `()`. Also setting as a Text Node value may be what's wanted... the question's unclear, but putting values straight into `innerHTML` is dangerous, may be a XSS hole.

Comment: @bobince Thanks. I know the question is very unclear but I am guessing the intention. I corrected the ().